# how to globally replace backslash with double backslash in a text file using bash?

Tags: string, bash, file

I create a file using `nano file.txt` . I typed in `Hello` hit enter and then typed `mate` so the input file looks like this:

```
Hello
mate
```

How do I replace the linefeed character in this file with `\\n` so that I can substitute this value later when I build valid json data, i.e. the expected output would be:

```
{"output":"Hello\\nmate"}
```

Right now this is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

expected_output=$(<file.txt)
expected_output=${expected_output//\\/\\\\}
JSON_FMT='{"output":"%s"}'
printf "%s" "$expected_output" >> aaa.txt
```

the file `aaa.txt` is being read by a different programming language where I decode the json.

Comment: I wonder why we're seeing so many questions using the `var=$(cat file)` anti-pattern these days. Weird...

Comment: Hi Ed, i was using var=$(< file) before and it worked on my local machine but it didnt work on fly.io's machine. :(

Comment: That'd be better if you needed to do that, of course, but it's extremely rare for reading the contents of a file into a variable using command substitution with a subshell like that to be the best approach to doing anything.

Comment: Why you want the output as `{"output":"Hello\\nmate"}`, instead of `{"output":"Hello\nmate"}` ?

Comment: @Raaz `$(<file)` is a bashism; are you sure fly.io isn't using a more limited POSIX shell like `dash`?

Comment: @chepner i am not sure because i dont know much about shell but thanks for letting me know. I can do more research on different type of shells.

Comment: @Philippe because in fly.io , when I make req to their machine via REST API I get back json data and I my json data that was returned from the bash was being invalid

Comment: @chepner now that i think abt it, i have deployed my own alpine docker image. i think that it's because of that image that i cant use `$(<file)`

Comment: Yes, I think alpine uses `ash` as the default shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input looks like this:

```
$ cat file
Hello
mate
```

and you want to replace all LineFeeds except the last one (assuming it's a valid POSIX text file) with `\\n` then you could do the following using any awk:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec sep $0; sep="\\\\n"} END{printf "{\"output\":\"%s\"}\n", rec}' file
{"output":"Hello\\nmate"}
```

---

Original answer when the OP said their input looked like:

```
$ cat file
Hello\nmate
```

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\\/\\\\/' file
Hello\\nmate

$ sed 's/\(.*\)\\\(.*\)/{"output":"\1\\\\\2"}/' file
{"output":"Hello\\nmate"}
```

Comment: Hey Ed, quick question. say the contents in the file was added by going to text editor and typing Hello then hit enter and then type mate. In that scenario, your solution and my solution dont seem to work. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes - your input would contain a LineFeed character, not the characters ```\``` and `n`.

Comment: thx Ed, that helped. TIL about linefeed and \n are different

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, you have to be careful with terminology around newlines - many people refer to newline as `\n` but it's not. A newline is a **string** that ends lines, so while it's linefeed (LF usually represented by `\n` or `$`) alone in Unix, in Windows it's carriage-return (CR usually represented by `\r` or `^M`, for `control-M`) plus linefeed ( `\r\n` or `^M$`) and in some other systems it's just CR and others it's LF CR. So you need to know what format of file you're dealing with, system your code runs on, and when/where to use `\r` and/or `\n` in code to match CR and/or LF.

Comment: thanks again Ed. I see that I need to be aware of these because they vary depending upon platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like `jq` to generate JSON. It already knows about what needs to be escaped and how to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

jq -sR '{output: .}' < file.txt >> aaa.txt
```

The `-sR` flag(s) cause the entire input to be read as a single string, rather than multiple JSON objects. The filter creates an object with `"output"` as the key and the entire input as the value.

Comment: That would output `\n`s instead of the `\\n`s the OP asked for. It'd also add a `\n` string at the end of the converted input, `"Hello\nmate\n"`, (assuming there is a newline at the end of the input file) which probably isn't desirable.

Comment: I have no idea why the OP specified that; I think they are mistaken. Whether or not there is a trailing newline depends on whether the input is a POSIX or DOS text file, not the `jq` filter itself.